# Adding a test user in graph api (javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add a couple to test users to an app I'm developing using google app engine and the javascript sdk. Following this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/):, I tried this code:

```
FB.api ('/app_id/accounts/test-users', 'post', {installed:'true', permissions:'read_stream'}, function (response) {
    alert (response.id);
});
```

(app_id was changed to the App ID as obtained in http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php)

But I get a popup "undefined". What is wrong with this code? I could not find any example for the javascript sdk.

As per the same facebook help page, response is supposed to be:

```
{ 
  "id": "1231....",  
   "access_token":"1223134..." , 
   "login_url":"https://www.facebook.com/platform/test_account.." 
}
```

BTW, if I log in as myself,

```
FB.api('/me', function(user) {
    welcomeMsg (user);
});
```

works just fine, so it's not a problem with app activation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to perform this type of task using the Javascript SDK, which is intended to make calls on behalf of a user, not an app.  For this type of call, it's necessary to authenticate as the app, and for that you need the app OAuth token and secret, which aren't available via Javascript (nor should they be, for security reasons).  So the best solution here is to make this call serverside. To do so, you should follow the ["App Login" instructions here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#authenticating-as-an-application) to get an app access token, and then pass that token in to the /app_id/accounts/test-users API call (as the "access_token" param)

Comment: Indeed, I tried alert (response.toSource()); and the response I got was: ({error:{type:"OAuthException", message:"(#15) The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session"}}). I was trying to follow exactly that link but my php skills are close to zero... I was trying to avoid learning another language. Do you know if it can be done with java on the server side (with facebook-java-api or similar)?

Comment: This link: [http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/) has a very nice tutorial to authenticate the app in java. It's very easy to implement as a servlet for gae.